# modx revo getresources multiple templates

Tags: modx, getresource

Is it possible to use multiple tpl's in the getResources call?

This is my code so far:

```
[[!getPage?
  &element=`getResources`
  &tpl=`overzichtTpl`
  &parents=`2, 74`
  &hideContainers=`0`
  &showHidden=`1`
  &limit=`50`
  &sortby=`RAND()`
  &depth=`0`
  &includeTVs=`1`
]]
```

What I want to achieve is the folowing: the resource call

```
&parent=`2`
```

has to use

```
&tpl=`overzichtTpl`
```

and the

```
&parent=`74`
```

has to use

```
&tpl=`overzichtAdvTpl`
```

Furthermore I want to have the output from both calls displayed at random. (otherwise I only have to use 2 seperate getResources calls). For example like this: 
[resource-call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFOQh.png)

If you have the solution, I'm looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly documented using tpl_N & tplnN:

https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources

If you need to randomize your templates, write a snippet and execute it from the getResources call (i.e. &tpl=`RandomizeChunkName`) You don't need an extra wrapper chunk.

Comment: Thnx for your comment. Reading the rtfm and some other posts, I've solved the puzzle using the following code:  &tplCondition=`template`  &conditionalTpls=`{"7":"overzichtTpl",  "27":"overzichtAdvTpl"}`. Your help made me think it over again and put me on the right track.  It works perfect now!!!